# floating div with same height

Tags: html, css

I have four div's floating. If the content of the first div is more, the border is not same across the four div's. But I want the border height to be increased based on the lengthy content across the four div's.

As given in this example, the first div is having more content so the border bottom height is not same across four div's. How can I make same height across four div's for different content in the div's.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 24.5%; border: 1px solid;">
            <span>This is a test span</span>  <span>This is a test span</span>  <span>This is a test span</span>  <span>This is a test span</span>  <span>This is a test span</span>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 24.5%; border-top: 1px solid; border-bottom: 1px solid;">Box2</div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 24.5%; border: 1px solid;">Box3</div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 24.5%; border: 1px solid;">Box4</div>
        <br style="clear: left;" />
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can only achieve this with currently not supported CSS settings (f. e. [display: flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/display)). Actually the easiest way in my opinion is to use JS-Libraries like [Equal Row](https://github.com/Sam152/Javascript-Equal-Height-Responsive-Rows) or [eqHeight](https://github.com/jsliang/eqHeight.coffee). There are also plugins without jQuery dependency around.

Comment: @Eich the flexbox support is not too bad by now: http://caniuse.com/flexbox

Comment: @NicoO thats correct. But if you have a look at the market share of Internet Explorer <10.... it makes me sad :/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to implement this. For example: 
1. Add class .container for your wrapper div

```
.container {
display: table;
width: 100%;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

.container div {
display: table-cell;
width: 24.5%; border: 1px solid;
}
```

[JsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/742Tu/)

and you can read about this problem [here](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/)

Answer (score 1):

## Please check the **[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CGXZ7/1/)** and your issue is resolved.

### Your HTML:

```
<div id="main-div">
    <div id="div1" style="float: left; width: 24.5%; border: 1px solid;"> <span>This is a test span</span>  <span>This is a test span</span>  <span>This is a test span</span>  <span>This is a test span</span>  <span>This is a test span</span>

    </div>
    <div id="div2" style="float: left; width: 24.5%; border-top: 1px solid; border-bottom: 1px solid;"><span>This is a test span</span>  <span>This is a test span</span>  <span>This is a test span</span>  <span>This is a test span</span>  <span>This is a test span</span><span>This is a test span</span>  <span>This is a test span</span>  <span>This is a test span</span>  <span>This is a test span</span>  <span>This is a test span</span><span>This is a test span</span>  <span>This is a test span</span>  <span>This is a test span</span>  <span>This is a test span</span>  <span>This is a test span</span>

    </div>
    <div id="div3" style="float: left; width: 24.5%; border: 1px solid;">Box3</div>
    <div id="div4" style="float: left; width: 24.5%; border: 1px solid;">Box4</div>
    <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>
```

### Some jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var div1 = $('#div1').height();
    var div2 = $('#div2').height();
    var div3 = $('#div3').height();
    var div4 = $('#div4').height();

    var largest = Math.max(div1, div2, div3, div4);
    $('#main-div div').height(largest + 'px');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a fixed `height` to all four divs manually just like you set the `width`.

If you want first div's `height` to be inherited to rest of the divs you have to use JavaScript. 
 Get the `height` of first div then set that value to rest of the div's `height`.

And please don't use inline styles, give them some id/class. Thus way you can manipulate them better.